# How to make <main> will be on the top of page like this near <header>

Tags: html, css, position, frontend

Here is the example:

[image: Here is the example]

Only main:

[image: Only main]

How to make  like a  margin ?
main have the blue border, header have yellow border.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for :(

Comment: @Alexey upload your html and css code that you have tried to achieve output

Comment: @Gaurav mean how to make full height and width for <Main> element
Open full screen screenshots in new tab

Answer (score -1):

If you want your `main` element to take up the full height of the page, you can use this CSS:

```
main {
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vh - heightOfHeaderInPixels);
}
```

I can't see your images on this WiFi connection, so I will just assume this is what you meant.